# Pass dynamic variable in matching or innerJoinWith in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am passing static value to my following query, then it works well. If I change it dynamic, then it doesn't.

```
 //works well
        $users = $this->Users->find('all')
                     ->where(['Users.role' => $role])
                     ->innerJoinWith('UserDetail',function($query){
                     return $query->where(['UserDetail.state' => "chandigarh"]); 
                   })->toArray();

       // don't work
         $state="chandigarh";
         $users = $this->Users->find('all')
                     ->where(['Users.role' => $role])
                     ->innerJoinWith('UserDetail',function($query){
                     return $query->where(['UserDetail.state' => "$state"]); 
                   })->toArray();
```

How can I pass my $state variable dynamic to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how PHP works, it's not really a CakePHP related problem

That variable is not available inside the scope of the anonymous function $query 
see example 3 here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

You should inherit the variable from the parent scope by using the USE contruct like this:

```
$state="chandigarh";
$users = $this->Users->find('all')
            ->where(['Users.role' => $role])
            ->innerJoinWith('UserDetail',function($query) use ($state) {
                  return $query->where(['UserDetail.state' => $state]); 
            })->toArray();
```

Comment: I would say it IS a CakePHP related problem since it is a really cumbersome solution...  Powerful but cumbersome to use.

Comment: but that is just the way anonymous functions work in PHP, how is that CakePHP's problem?

Comment: Alex, it is the way it is implemented. I can't become friend with cakephp3's innerJoinWith() and other functions depending on anonymous functions, there are too many ways to do it wrong. Most things are better than cakephp2, but this is not one of the things.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove "" that cover `"$state"` that should be:  `$query->where(['UserDetail.state' => $state])` not `$query->where(['UserDetail.state' => "$state"])`