# CakePHP 3: [ManyToMany] Getting Bookmarks with MULTIPLE specific tags

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to archive somthing quite similar to the Bookmark Tutorial here: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html#getting-bookmarks-with-a-specific-tag

To find Bookmarks with the Tags "funny", "cat", "gifs" This query is usable in the BookmarksController:

```
$tags = ['funny','cat','gifs'];
$bookmarks = $this->Bookmarks->find();
  ->innerJoinWith('Tags')
  ->where(['Tags.title IN ' => $tags]);
  ->group(['Bookmarks.id']);

$this->set('result',$tags);
```

This returns the Bookmarks tagged with funny **OR** cat **OR** gifs.

Im trying to change this to return only Bookmarks taged with funny **AND** cat **AND** gifs.

Does anyone has a hint how to archive this?

Comment: Sounds like **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938440/how-to-match-records-that-are-associated-with-a-specific-set-of-other-records**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got it working. This is how

```
$current_tags = ['funny','cat','gifs']
$query = $this->Bookmarks->find()->contain(['Tags'])
            ->matching('Tags', function($query) use ($current_tags){
                return $query->where(['Tags.name IN' => $current_tags]);
            });
            $query->group('Bookmarks.id')->having([
        $this->Bookmarks->query()->newExpr('COUNT(DISTINCT Tags.name) = '.count($current_tags))
    ]);
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556925/5554802) i solved a problem i had after follwoing the comented answer above. The Problem appears when using variables for the array to search in. in this case $current_tags.

matching([...]) is using an anonymous function.
anonymous functions have a new scope. This is why the variable has to be inherited using use().